# Why I cant print out control identifiers?

Tags: python, url, browser, pywinauto

**Summary:**
I am trying to establish a seamless connection with the browser's URL box and extract the current URL efficiently. In the PyWinAuto library, the "print_control_identifiers" function is designed to generate a list of identifiers similar to those from inspect.exe. Although I am making progress towards this goal and recognizing the value of accessing control identifiers, I currently face a challenge hindering the printing of these identifiers. Nevertheless, I am actively exploring alternative strategies to overcome this obstacle and expect a successful resolution soon.

**The code:**

```py
import time
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application")
print(dir((app["New tab - Brave"]["Enter the URL or name of web page"].print_control_identifiers)))
app["New tab - Brave"]["Enter the URL or name of web page"].print_control_identifiers()
```

**Questions:**

Is it conceivable that the URL address could be concealed or embedded within a specific panel of the browser interface(or control identifiers)?

Is there a means to extract the control identifiers pertaining to the child elements of the application?